# How to get RU of a query in Dependencies through Application Insights Analytics Tool?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-cosmosdb, request-unit

I want to find RU of each query through application insight analytics tool. I've run the following query:

```
dependencies
| where type == "Azure DocumentDB"
```

But there is no sign for RU of the run query. Also, there is not any thing in `customDimensions` column:

[image]

I should have mentioned that there is a duration column which is not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to turn on [HeaderTelemetry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2016/11/03/including-headers-for-request-events-with-application-insights/).

Then you can probably join the `dependencies` and `requests` tables like so:

```
dependencies | where type == "Azure DocumentDB" | join (
   requests 
) on operation_Id
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-correlation), `operation_Id` is the field to correlate.

The [response headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#response-headers) should be on the `customDimensions` attributes.